# objects property undefined, even if not true

Tags: javascript, object

Why is the objects property undefined, when logging the whole object, that is not the case.

this the log:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
[{"id":"base_data","title":"Base Data","widgetId":"base_data"}] 


console.log(obj.title);
undefined
```

why???

Comment: var rt = JSON.stringify(obj); then rt.title this will work

Comment: @cracker — No. That will try to get the title property of **a string**.

Comment: @Quentin yeah i got this now thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

Your object (`{}`) is inside an array (`[]`), and you are trying to access the `title` property of the array, not the object.

```
console.log(obj[0].title);
```

Answer (score 0):

is it an Array? try

```
console.log(obj[0].title);
```